# How can I encrypt some arbitrary data using an asymmetrical algorithm with the private key in C# under .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-3.5

I'm looking for a way to encrypt some data on C#, running on .NET 3.5. The encryption must be done using an asymmetric algorithm, and it must use the private key to encrypt.

The  `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class that comes with the .NET framework only provides public key encryption, so that one's out; and, despite I did look for some library to do this, I wasn't able to find any that would solve the issue that doesn't rely on the `System.Numerics.BigInteger`class, which is .NET 4.0 (or maybe 4.5, but still doesn't work in 3.5).

Ideally, what I'd want is to be able to either use a library that does this work, or to be able to write (without having to rewrite some algorithm implementation from scratch) a class that does something like this:

```
public class SomeAlgorithm {
  public SomeAlgorithm (string xmlKey) {
    // something
  }

  public byte[] encrypt (byte[] data, bool usePrivateKey) {
    // note that data should be able to take an arbitrarily large size
    // I don't expect it to become any larger than 300 or 400 bytes, but
    // the implementation should be able to handle arbitrary-size data

    // do something
  }

  public byte[] decrypt (byte[] encryptedData, bool usePrivateKey) {
    // the same constraints apply to encryptedData here

    // do something
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm not looking for signing, I actually need to encrypt all the data with the private key. I am aware that this is not the normal way the algorithms are used, and of the security implications of being able to decrypt data with a public key. An implementation based on signing and symmetric encryption would not be useful in this particular case. The requirements here are a bit bizarre, but in the end, I actually need to do it this way. I've noticed that similar questions here have received majorly negative responses that actually didn't solve the problem at all, so I'm adding this disclaimer.

Comment: Encrypt with private key? Perhaps in your scenario both parties should have their own public/private key pair, no? That way, both could encrypt using each other's public key.

Comment: @dcastro The problem is that, in this case, the encryption key is the one that must be kept private. The security concerns are similar to those of signing (and that's why, like with signing, I'm intending to use a private key to encrypt). It's not exactly a signature, though; and that's why a signature implementation won't work for me; but the security concerns are similar.

Comment: With out you describing your security requirements and why signatures are inapplicable it's hard to help you. Proper padding is essential for RSA security and if you do something unusual the default padding might not be secure.

Comment: Perhaps you want a signature scheme with message recovery

Comment: @CodesInChaos If padding is needed, then the implementation should handle that, too. (Either whatever library/implementation I find or the one I write.) At any rate, the data I'm encrypting isn't that valuable, so an attack by a hacker with a million dollars to spend and 2 months of time isn't a concern (the data is worth much less). As for what I'm doing, as I said, it's not exactly a signature, but it pretty much works as if it was a signature with extra fields (concatenated to the hash). In a way, I need to reimplement something signing-like, so I need the private key encryption for that.